# Concatenation overwrites string and is mixed up

Tags: perl, concatenation

I recently wrote a converter, which takes our old Wiki pages and converts them into SharePoint Pages.

All this was done via command line, but now I switched to GUI with Win32.

I'm still new to Perl and just copied my working code to my `new.pl` with fancy GUI things.

Everything works expect this line:

```perl
$newFileName = 'Pages/'.$file.'.aspx';
```

It should output a path to my directory (`Pages/TheFileName.aspx`) where I store the converted pages.

However I get this when I print `$newFileName`:

```
.aspx/TheFileName
```

`.aspx` overwrites Pages instead of being concatenated at the end.

I've tried hundreds of other combinations but the second concatenation just overwrites my text. It's the exact same line, which is working in my other script.

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that you've read `$file` from STDIN. If so, you may want to ensure you `chomp;` it. This looks exactly the sort of thing you get if you have accidentally included a linefeed or carriage return in your filename.

Comment: It comes from a textfield input in which the user enters the old Wiki urls. each line is stored in an array and `$file` is an element of it. `chomp` did not help :( same behaviour  EDIT: I had the same problem some weeks back but can't remember how I resolved it. There it was `<STDIN>`

Comment: We need to see more code to help then. Might want to try stripping 'linefeed/carriage return' with `$file =~ s/[\r\n]//g;` and see if that hepls.

Comment: I strongly believe the problem is in the `$file` . try to print `$file` before assigning to the `$newFileName`. I think then you will know the problem.

Comment: `$file =~ s/[\r\n]//g;` Did the trick! As you guys mentioned the problem came from $file itself, many thanks!

Comment: It's almost always best to use `s/\s+\z//` instead of `chomp`, as it will remove all carriage-returns and linefeeds as well as trailing spaces and tabs that are probably unwanted. If you just want to remove all line-endings from the end of a string (CR, LF, or CRLF) then use `s/\R+\z//`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact content of $newFileName seems to be

```
"Pages/TheFileName\r.aspx"
```

which, when printed out looks like

```
.aspx/TheFileName
```

because included "\r" (carriage return) causes cursor to go to start of the line so that ".aspx" overwrites "Pages" on screen.

So simple fix (as already mentioned in comments) is to remove "\r" from $file, e.g. with

```
$file =~ s/\r//g;
```

Problems like this can be quite common in Windows because in Windows newline is "\r\n" while many unix-like programs except "\n", so it's easy to have that extra "\r" left in strings.